# How to create on demand instances?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, asynchronous, cdi

When calling a Java method on which you must pass a new instance as a parameter, how is it possible that this new instance is created by CDI container ?

In the following example: I'm adding a listener to an aynchronous servlet context:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/example", asyncSupported = true)
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req,
        final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

        // ... some code

        AsyncContext aCtx = req.startAsync(req, resp);
        aCtx.addListener(**new AsyncListener()** {
             // implementation of the async listener
        });
        // ...
    }
}
```

So instead of manually performing this new AsyncListener() instantiation, I would like it to be created by the CDI container.

Of course, I want every aync context having its own listener instance, otherwise I would just have injected an AsyncListener with @Inject as a field of the servlet class.

For now, couldn't find any way to do this.
Somebody has an idea to share ?

Answer (score 5):

Inject an [`Instance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) of your listener. If the listener class is in dependent scope, then every call to `get()` will yield a new instance.

```
@Inject
private Instance<MyAsyncListener> listenerFactory;
```

And:

```
    aCtx.addListener(listenerFactory.get());
```

I've called the variable `listenerFactory` because that's how it's being used here.

I tested this on JBoss AS7.1.1, which uses Weld 1.1.5 as its CDI provider, but i believe this to be standard behaviour.

Comment: Also beware of the well documented memory leak in CDI 1.0 with Instance and dependent scoped objects injected into larger scoped objects, but for what you're doing you should be fine.

Comment: @LightGuard: Good point, but i have to confess i'm not sure why this case is safe. Is it because a servlet isn't considered a scoped bean?

Comment: It actually did the job. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The more i think about this, the more i think is that the answer is to do some sorcery to create a new request scope for the async thread, then simply summon up an instance of the listener in that scope. I'm not entirely sure how to do that, though.

Comment: @TomAnderson In this case the servlet doesn't have a scope and by the looks of his code it's stateless so even if the container creates a lot of them they'll get GC'd quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Injection points of a bean are processed when the bean is instantiated, so unfortunately you cannot explicitly trigger injection. This may (and hopefully will) change in later releases of CDI.

One approach I am aware of that can be used in some cases to work around that restriction is to encapsulate or derive the class you want to inject into, providing it with an injectable field or an initializer method. In this case it would be the `AsyncContext`, but you have no control over what the `HttpServletRequest` will return, so this option is not applicable here.

Maybe you could work something out using the [CDI BeanManager](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) - but I'm afraid this would need significantly more effort than calling `new`